# Seems cin.putback(char) does nothing in theory

Tags: c++

I found the function `basic_istream::putback()` inherited form `basic_ios` calls `basic_streambuf::sputbackc()` which in turn calls `pbackfail()`. And it is funny when I found `pbackfail()` does nothing but returning `eof` (and it's not `overrided`).

So how does the function `putback()` work in practice?

Comment: I would suggest going with what the [documentation](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_istream/putback) says rather than digging through stl code. `putbackfail` might be doing something like setting a variable to indicate that the last character was not read or something similar

Comment: I just found it does do nothing. So the question is not needed.

Comment: I just found it does something; I wish it DID always call pbackfail() ;).